# sytemctl status log output

Tags: systemctl

When I run systemctl status with multiple services at once like

`sudo systemctl status myservice1 myservice2 myservice3` I see the output, but in the end I see

`lines 1-48/48 (END)`
or if the output is even larger with more arguments

`lines 1-62`
and I can scroll or paginate the output and quit with q.

Can this behavior be changed that all log output is printed at once and the command exits?

Answer (score 13):

Two options:

- `PAGER=cat systemctl status service1 service2 service3`
- `systemctl --no-pager status service1 service2 service3`

Explanation:

Those `lines 1-62` messages are produced by a pager program, the commonly used ones are `more` and `less`. Pager programs intend to make output more user-friendly, scrollable, etc. They are especially important on less feature-rich terminal emulators.

The pager program to use is controlled by `PAGER` environment variable. By setting `PAGER` to `cat` we replace fancier `more` or `less` with a much more simple pager which actually does not do any paging.

Alternative is to pass `--no-pager` to `systemctl` which tells it not to invoke pager program at all.

Comment: `cat` is not necessary. It works to simply have `PAGER` be empty, e.g. `PAGER= systemctl status ...`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, providing environment variable PAGER or the option --no-pager messed up my terminal display (with weird dots display):

[image: systemctl status --no-pager suricata]

So, I just use this way:

`sudo systemctl status myservice1 myservice2 myservice3 | cat`